# Synchronizing Playback of Multiple Audio Files in Audio Kit

Tags: swift, audiokit

I am developing a small audio sequencer application using AudioKit. I only need to play back 4 channels of audio. However I need to play them back perfectly synchronized down to the sample level. When I run a test using just two audio files, I can hear that they are not synchronized. The difference is only a few samples, but even a one sample discrepancy would be a problem. I am currently using multiple AKClipPlayer objects routed to an AKMixer object. I called him with the basics for loop like this:

```
   private var clipPlayers : [AKClipPlayer] = []

   func play(){
        for player in clipPlayers{
            player.play()
        }
    }
```

Is sample accurate playback timing of multiple audio files possible using AudioKit?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need to schedule playback to start in the future with `play(at:)`.

```
// This can take longer than expected, so do this before choosing a future time
clipPlayers.forEach { $0.prepare(withFrameCount: 10_000) }

let nearFuture = AVAudioTime.now() + 0.2
clipPlayers.forEach { $0.play(at: nearFuture) }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion exactly (I was in the process of trying something similar myself) and the result was a "washing machine sound". I should mention that what I'm trying to do is phase invert a track and use it to cancel out another track. I assume the sound I heard was the result of the tracks being almost synchronized but not quite. Additional thoughts? When by total accident the tracks happen to start at exactly the same time I hear the desired result which is silence.

Comment: I think the clip player is pretty accurate, but the only way to tell is to test!

Comment: I scheduled them to play in the future and unfortunately that still did not produce a sample accurate result. I am flipping the phase of one file and using it to cancel unwanted artifacts in the recording of the other file. This only works if the samples are exactly aligned. When they are aligned the result is silence. When they are not aligned the original signal is not attenuated by much.

Comment: In AudioKit no I did not. Having two files be "approximately" synchronized is fine for consumer audio, but for pro audio it is certain death. I ended up having to write a hack solution where I bounced the files, then played them back to guarantee sample accurate synchronization.